# Matching SID from AD and Event Viewer

Tags: powershell, active-directory, event-viewer

I'm trying to make a script that searches AD for locked accounts, as well as parses the Security log in Event Viewer and then compare the SID's, and if they match, display information of the user that has the SID.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$PDC = "DOMAINCONTROLLER"
$UserInfo = Search-ADAccount -LockedOut
$LockedOutEvents = Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $PDC -FilterHashtable 
@{LogName='Security';Id=4740} | Sort-Object -Property * -Descending
Foreach($Event in $LockedOutEvents){
If($Event.Properties[2] -Match $UserInfo.SID.value)
{
  $Event | Select-Object -Property @(
    @{Label = 'User'; Expression = {$_.Properties[0].Value}}
    @{Label = 'DomainController'; Expression = {$_.MachineName}}
    @{Label = 'EventId'; Expression = {$_.Id}}
    @{Label = 'LockoutTimeStamp'; Expression = {$_.TimeCreated}}
    @{Label = 'Message'; Expression = {$_.Message -split "`r" | Select -First 1}}
    @{Label = 'LockoutSource'; Expression = {$_.Properties[1].Value}}
    )
}}
```

There seems to be an issue with the arguments in the If statement `If($Event.Properties[2] -Match $UserInfo.TargetSID)`

The output of $Event.Properties[2] is like this:

```
 Value                                        
 -----                                        
 S-1-1-1-111111111-111111111-111111111-22222
```

The output of $UserInfo.SID.Value:

`S-1-1-1-111111111-111111111-111111111-11111
 S-1-1-1-111111111-111111111-111111111-11111
 S-1-1-1-111111111-111111111-111111111-22222
 S-1-1-1-111111111-111111111-111111111-11111
 S-1-1-1-111111111-111111111-111111111-11111`

As you can see one SID is found in both outputs but when matching these two i get "False" as a response. Does anyone have any idea why this happens?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you tried `$Event.Properties[2].Value -Match $UserInfo.TargetSID` ?

Comment: I would try to add `.toString()` to both variables like: `$Event.Properties[2].toString() -match $UserInfo.SID.value.toString()`

Comment: @Paxz $UserInfo.TargetSID Does not return anything but but when I run it it responds with true :/

Comment: @TobyU That does not return the SID numbers;
<code>$Event.Properties[2].toString()
System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventProperty</code

<code>$UserInfo.SID.value.toString()
System.Object[]</code>

Comment: I think you need to convert the binary SID value in `$UserInfo.SID.value` to string first using something like this: `$userSID = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier $UserInfo.SID.value, 0` and next compare that to the`$Event.Properties[2].Value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're comparing a `SecurityIdentifier` object to an array of strings (at least that output looks like it's an array - you can use `$UserInfo.SID.value.GetType()` to make sure). There are two issues with your current code:

1. The `-Match` operator only works with two strings, so you can't use that here. But you can use `Contains()` on the array.
2. You need to convert the `SecurityIdentifier` to a string. The `Value` property does that.

Try this:

```
If ($UserInfo.SID.value.Contains($Event.Properties[2].Value))
```

Comment: Thank you. Adding another .value gives the correct match: 

If($UserInfo.SID.value.Contains($Event.Properties[2].Value.value))